# Rails: How to include Custom folder path in assest folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails. I am trying to figure out how to include custom folder path since i m using bootstrap and its tries to load some fonts from specific path which is "/assets/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.woff2" hence i have created the folder themes inside assest folder, inside themes folder i have created default folder .. so on  till fonts folder and i have kept  icons.woff2 inside fonts folder. how can i include this path into my project  i m still getting resource not found exception

```
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.ttf 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0):

For bootstrap you can include the folder fonts into your assets and for rails 4+ you can just use the *font-url* helper . A standard that should work for the glyphicons is

```
@at-root {
  // Import the fonts
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: font-url('bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: font-url('bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), font-url('bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), font-url('bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), font-url('bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), font-url('bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
}
```

Works with current bootstrap and rails 4+
the font-url helper points automatically to app/assets/fonts

Comment: thanks for your reply sir, but url which i have mentioned comes dynamically i cannot change it. Is there is any way to translate this path in rails

Comment: What do you mean dynamically? In Rail assets are compiled at deploy time. If you have something like theme switching at runtime you need a  very different solution.